# Arrow characters height when draw on HTML5 canvas in MacOS X

Tags: javascript, html, macos, canvas

When I draw arrows characters on HTML5 canvas using fillText method, in MacOS X I get arrows with different height when I draw them separately. But when I draw them as a single line, the height is the same.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font = "16px Courier";

// draw two arrows as separate strings
ctx.fillText("↑", 50, 50);
ctx.fillText("↓", 60, 50);

// draw two arrows as a single string
ctx.fillText("↑↓", 50, 66);
```

And I get this result in Chrome:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/72zIf.png

Why in the first line down arrow is smaller? It's the same characters, I just copy and paste them.

Also in Safari the down arrow is smaller in both cases:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvd4N.png

In other OS (tested in Linux) heights of arrows are the same.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAzNk.png

Comment: You can check the font may not be installed in mac. SO it may go to the default font. Else add font file in HTML body.

Comment: Yes, this happens with Courier font. Changed font to Menlo and the issue has gone. Thanks.